# Image in gridview in yii2

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

How to put an image in GridView in yii2?I have the following code. But its not displaying the image as it is not giving any image url. Where to put the image url?

```
 <?php echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'c_id',
        'name:ntext',
        'description:ntext',
        array(
                'format' => 'image',
               'attribute'=>'logo',

),

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Comment: what is the html output in the cell?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try like,

```
 array(
'format' => 'image',
'value'=>function($data) { return $data->imageurl; },

   ),
```

And in your model,

```
public function getImageurl()
{
return \Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl.'/<path to image>/'.$this->logo;
}
```

Don't know this is the right way or not.But this works for me.

Comment: This getImageurl() is like magic. but I think now we use @Insane Skull 's answer more often..

Answer (score 13):

Use this:

```
   [
        'attribute' => 'image',
        'format' => 'html',    
        'value' => function ($data) {
            return Html::img(Yii::getAlias('@web').'/images/'. $data['image'],
                ['width' => '70px']);
        },
    ],
```

Comment: you can also use columnLabel to set the label for column.

Answer (score 2):

Yii 2 has built-in helper for building urls. You can bulld the url to image by path too (by passing second parameter `$scheme`).

So I recommend using this:

**GridView:**

```
use yii\helpers\Url;

[
    'format' => 'image',
    'value' => function ($model) {
        return $model->getImageUrl(); 
    },
],
```

**Model:**

```
public function getImageUrl()
{
    return Url::to('@web/path/to/logo/' . $this->logo, true);
}
```

Comment: how do I set the width of the image?

Comment: You can create separate question for that since the current problem is solved.

Comment: I commented on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677501/set-width-image-in-gridview-yii2/22885563#22885563)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one:

```
 <?= GridView::widget
                ([
                    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                     'filterModel' => $searchdata,
        'columns' => [
                      [
                         'attribute' => 'logo',
                         'format' => 'html',
                         'label' => 'Image',
                         'value' => function ($data) {
                                    return Html::img('/advanced/hello/frontend/web/image/' . $data['logo'],
                                    ['width' => '80px',
                                     'height' => '80px']);
                                   },
                     ],
                    ],
                 ]);
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In views->image->index.php

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,

        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
             [
             'attribute'=>'image_path',
            'label'=>'Image',
            'format'=>'html',
            'content' => function($data){
                $url = $data->getParentName();
                return Html::img($url, ['alt'=>'yii','width'=>'250','height'=>'100']);
                        }
            ],
            'caption1',
            'caption2',
            'status',
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
        'tableOptions' =>['class' => 'table table-striped table-bordered'],

    ]); ?>
```

In model->image

```
 public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Image::className(), ['image_id' => 'image_id']);
    }
    public function getParentName()
    {
        $model=$this->parent;
        return $model?$model->image_path:'';
    }
```

table attributes are,
image_id,image_path,caption1,caption2,status

Answer (score 1):

I used to use 'raw' format for this type of work.

```
[
    "attribute": "image",
    "format": "raw",
    "value": function($model){
        return ($model->image) ? Html::img("/path-to-img-location" . $model->image) : false;
    }
]
```

if image exists then image is displayed otherwise it is blank.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
public function getImageurl()
{
  return \Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('@web/path/to/logo/'.$this->logo);
}
```

'*@web*' is a [predefined path aliases](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-advanced-app.html#predefined-path-aliases).

['*urlManager->CreateUrl()*'](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html#createUrl()-detail) do something more than resolving aliases.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple you can just declare it in your index file as below.

```
[
            'label' => Your Label Here',  
            'format' => 'raw',   
            'value' => function ($data) {
                 $images = '';

                $images = $images.Html::img(\Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl.'/your-path-here/'.$date->getImagefilename(),['alt'=>'','width'=>'30','height'=>'30', 'data-toggle'=>'tooltip','data-placement'=>'left','title' => $name->pictogram_comment ,'style'=>'cursor:default;']);
                return ($images);

            }
            ],
```

You will have to get image instance from your model. If required example please comment, will get back on that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'c_id',
        'name:ntext',
        'description:ntext',
        'logo:image',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```