# Set width image in gridview yii2

Tags: php, image, gridview, yii2

how to set width image in gridview widget in yii2?

I've been using this method to display the image.
[Image in gridview in yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880511/image-in-gridview-in-yii2)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can define class for cells as in example

```
[
    'attribute' => 'title',
    'format' => 'image',
    'value' => function($data) { return 'you_image.jpeg'; },
    'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'come-class']
],
```

Then set image width using css. If image width can be different, use html format

```
[
    'attribute' => 'title',
    'format' => 'html',
    'value' => function($data) { return Html::img('you_image.jpeg', ['width'=>'100']); },
],
```

Comment: @kopletusprime @Alex doesn't work for me. I have `'value'=>function($data) { return $data->imageurl; }`, which is NOT a static image URL. so where do I put `['width'=>'100']`??? I tried everything where I think it fits but I got errors

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
'value' => function($data) {
        return Html::img($data->imageurl,['width'=>100]);
   },
```

And in your model:

```
  /*
    Return Image url path
  */
   public function getimageurl()
   {
      // return your image url here
      return \Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl.'/uploads/'.$this->ImagePath;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
'format' => ['image',['width'=>'100','height'=>'100']],
```

example:

```
[           
      'attribute' => 'image',
      'format' => ['image',['width'=>'100','height'=>'100']],
      'value' => function($dataProvider) { return $dataProvide->image; },


],
```