# Displaying an image in kartik grid shows the path

Tags: yii, yii2-advanced-app

I have a grid and i would like to implement an image but it always returns the path to the image

this is the code:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'picture',
    'value'=>function($data) { return $data->imageurl; },
    'value' => function ($data) {
        return Html::img(Yii::getAlias('@web').'/images/user_accounts.png',
            ['width' => '70px']);
    },

],
```

The above idea i got from [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880511/image-in-gridview-in-yii2) but it fails

I have also tried  :

```
[
    'attribute' => 'picture',
    'value'=>function($data) { return $data->imageurl; },

],
```

And added

```
public function getImageurl()
  {
      return \Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl.'/images/user_accounts.png';
  }
```

But it still fails to display the image to the grid

This is what is displayed
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'picture',
    'format' => 'html',    
    'value' => function ($data) {
        return Html::img(Yii::getAlias('@web').'/images/'. $data['imageurl'],
            ['width' => '70px']);
    },
],
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [format](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-datacolumn.html#$format-detail) attribute of the DataColumn class, by default it uses the text format, so the content is displayed as text instead of html. Use the raw or html formatters

Answer (score 0):

```
>>>This may be helpfull too...  
          [  
            'attribute' => 'picture',  
            'format' => 'html',  
            'value' => function ($data) {  
                    return Html::img($data->imageurl,['width' => '80px']);  
             },  
             'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,  
             'filter' => '',  
             'filterWidgetOptions' => [  
                'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true],  
              ],  
              'filterInputOptions' => ['placeholder' => 'Image Url'],  
          ],
```